# Semantic Segmentation: Data formats

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I am new to semantic segmentation and have a lot of problems with the things you do not see in tutorials: How the data should "look" at any given step.

Currently, I have a U-Net which is supposed to do a binary segmentation of aerial images into trees/other land cover (more classes are planned in case this is working).

Problem: The training process runs for a while, accuracy goes up to 1 (which is conspicuous in itself) and the trained model predicts just 0 everywhere, no matter the input image.

I have read that data format, namely whether the color values are `Int8`, `float32`, etc. can be an issue. However, I do not know what the format should be, so I do not know if this is the problem. At the moment, my mask images are of type `float32` with dimentsions (batchsize, 256, 256, 1).
Is this how it should be, or should the masks e.g. be `Int8`? Could this be a reason why the results are terrible at the moment?

The training images are (batchsize, 256, 256, 4) (RGBa images) also in `float32`. Model predictions are one-hot encoded (output layer of shape (batchsize, 256, 256, 2) for the 2 classes which I currently use). My implementation of the CNN is using `tf.keras`.

Please comment if further information is required to find out what is wrong.

**Edit:** About 30% of the area is class "trees" (= 0), the rest is class "other" (= 1). I tried to upload a TensorBoard [here](https://tensorboard.dev/experiment/9vqwWWL3QHaTxCGrS8p0ug/#scalars) (had some trouble making it work, unfortunately it had no Name when it was uploaded).

This is the Python output:

```
256/256 [==============================] - 121s 434ms/step - loss: 0.8407 - updated_mean_io_u: 0.3848 - accuracy: 0.0039 - val_loss: 0.6496 - val_updated_mean_io_u: 0.3762 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
256/256 [==============================] - 108s 424ms/step - loss: 0.6294 - updated_mean_io_u: 0.3823 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.6159 - val_updated_mean_io_u: 0.3791 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
256/256 [==============================] - 109s 425ms/step - loss: 0.6007 - updated_mean_io_u: 0.3829 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.5971 - val_updated_mean_io_u: 0.3757 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
256/256 [==============================] - 109s 428ms/step - loss: 0.5826 - updated_mean_io_u: 0.3437 - accuracy: 0.4609 - val_loss: 0.5815 - val_updated_mean_io_u: 0.1231 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 5/5
256/256 [==============================] - 110s 431ms/step - loss: 0.5695 - updated_mean_io_u: 0.1178 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5746 - val_updated_mean_io_u: 0.1247 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
```

...rather strange "jumps" in accuracy between 0 and 1; model predicts only "0" which isn't even the larger class...

Comment: My first questions: are your data classes balanced ? if trees are only present in 1% of cases, it is easy to predict no tree at all, all the time ... Can you also show us a learning curve with train and test results, and a confusion matrix ?

Comment: I added some output from during the model fit. Accuracy is probably a bad indicator, so I included a custom Intersection Over Union (updated_mean_io_u) measure which appears to behave totally different from accuracy...